# dynamic templating - props for child component should be reactive but are not

Tags: vue.js

I started Vue.js two days ago and I already need your help.

I have a state machine component which renders a child component passed as parameter. Because I do not know in advance which component I am going to display and the props it takes, I am using `render` functions instead of templates for the state machine parent component.

Code excerpt goes like this :

```js
  function render(h) {
    const app = this;
    props.reduce((acc, key) => ((acc[key] = app[key]), acc), currentPropsObj);
    console.log("child props", currentPropsObj);

    return app.hasStarted
      ? h(
          renderComponent,
          {
            // copy the props from the machine vue component to the render component
            props: Object.assign({}, currentPropsObj)
          },
          []
        )
      : h("div", {}, "LoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLoLo");
  }

  return Vue.component(name, {
    render,
    data: function() {
      return initialData;
    },
    methods: {
      set: function(stateObj) {
        Object.keys(stateObj).forEach(key => (this[key] = stateObj[key]));
      }
    },
```

The issue is that the dynamic `renderComponent` does not seem to take into account the `props` it (should) receives as parameter. I checked that `currentPropsObj` is correctly computed. Using Vue devtool, I also checked that the `Search` child component (the one I am using in the demo) props are not udpated when its parent data is updated.

For a full demo and reproduction, I made a codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/m5jzqw9w3y

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Where are `props` and `currentPropsObj` defined?

Comment: please check the codesandbox, the whole code is there. The file is `vue-state-driven.js`. The props that you see there is an array of strings, each string being a prop

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know about that. I can't post the whole thing here. And codesandbox cannot be embedded in here

Comment: I don't see any props defined for your `Search` component so how could it possibly receive any?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Where would you define the props in Search?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

Comment: yeah that seems to be working. Jesus Christ. I put them in `data` instead.  Thanks Phil. If you want to write that quickly down I'll be happy to accept it straight away. Spent a few hours on that already, can't believe it was that easy.

Comment: The confusing part of the documentation for me was that the props thing seems to be connected to usage with `View.component(...)`. Other examples I reviewed had the reactive info in `data`, so got mistaken here. Just started two days ago, I hope there aren't many of those.

Comment: It's more of a _typo_ type problem. Glad you got it sorted though. You might also be interested in dynamic components ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: yeah I saw those, but I was not sure it would work.The `render ` function looked life a safer bet. I'll try it though. The issue was passing the props to the child component, knowing that the child knows its props, but the state machine parent doesn't so it is hard to have a fixed template. I am used to VNode and hyperscript, so the render function looked more flexible.

Comment: just noted that there are two people who apparently recommended that the question be closed because... it does not appear to be about programming?? Given such a lack of either judgement or knowledge (or maybe they just did not read the question), I would recommend that they stop judging other people's question or improve their undersanding of the subject matter.

Comment: I'm one of those voters. There's a sub-section to that vote option about it being _"no longer a problem or a typographical error"_. We're not all horrible people here, I promise 

Comment: happy to hear that.

Comment: still I want to say that this is not very friendly to beginner. I am quite knowledgeable about rxjs  I answered 200+ of such questions, most of them sounding pretty stupid. I actually, on a bad day, fell into the trap of speaking condescendently to some people. That is not a good behaviour. Whatever question as stupid as it is, is a real problem for the one asking. Additionally because they are new to something, they do not even know how to describe properly the problem they have. Once past my overzealous period, I understood that the most important is to help, then comes quality of the Q&A.

Comment: whatever were your first impulse you were very helpful and I am grateful.